Why did Kamala Harris once describe her own appearance at the start of an important meeting?
Background
At the start of an important discussion, Kamala Harris describes her appearance:

I am ... sitting at the table wearing a blue suit.

This is being used as an argument against her potential run for presidency:

Question
I haven't encountered this convention before and am curious why she did (/does ?) it.

Is this really a political question? Not a single one of your points hints at a political angle, and it does not seem like you are asking for one.

@MisterMiyagi fair question. I'm not sure, I think the linked post of the meeting is intended as a sort of (political) attack on Harris (possibly taking her statement out of context), so I am curious if there is context to her making the statement that the short video misses. When I watch the video, I am puzzled as to why she does it, however, I am as far from an expert as one can be. tl;dr I'm just curious.

A politician, at a political event/meeting... it's entirely politics.  It's a politician trying to connect with and ingratiate themselves to a specific subset of the voters.  It's easier to catch flies with honey, than it is with vinegar.  And people tend to make decisions from an emotional level moreso than a logical/rational level.  So, you make someone feel seen/heard for a minute, you gain that goodwill, and you likely get that vote.

I think (but have no proof) that she may be describing her appearance because attendees of the event are wearing masks and the attendees and the audience may have trouble identifying who is speaking without seeing their mouth move.
By stating that she is a woman sitting at the table wearing a blue suit, people can look for the person who matches the description and identify her as the speaker.
